# Is there a list of known rate laws for reactions?

Tags: kinetics, reference-request

I've been scouring the web for a website/pdf that lists/tabulates reactions and their corresponding rate laws. Something like:
\begin{align}
\ce{A + B &-> C} & \text{rate}&=1.234[\ce{A}]^2[\ce{B}] &&\text{at } 25~^\circ\mathrm{C}\\
\ce{D + E &-> F} & \text{rate}&=5.678[\ce{D}][\ce{E}]^2 &&\text{at } 25~^\circ\mathrm{C}\\  
\ce{G + H &-> I} & \text{rate}&=9.001[\ce{G}][\ce{H}] &&\text{at } 25~^\circ\mathrm{C}\\
&\cdots&&\cdots&&\cdots\end{align}

Is there such a list of known rate laws for reactions?

Comment: If this exists, I would be euphoric.

Comment: Like this? http://kinetics.nist.gov/kinetics/index.jsp Though it seems there is no data for reaction in the liquid phase, which is probably what most chemists are interested in.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto That's similar to what I'm thinking, but I'm looking more for a ready-made list of the rate laws, i.e. not requiring you to enter the reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Integrated Rate Laws in Chemical Kinetics are very well known (http://www.csus.edu/indiv/m/mackj/chem142/kinetics.pdf).

Here is a good article with the list of the constants: [Table of Recommended Rate Constants for Chemical Reactions Occurring in Combustion](https://web.archive.org/web/20160804015722/http://www.nist.gov/data/nsrds/NSRDS-NBS67.pdf) by Francis Westley

Comment: How does the first link answer the question? It has 22pages of a PPT and only a handful of examples are given, the rest is just textbook theory on kinetics.